# Failed to find MPU6050 with ESP32

Tags: arduino, esp32, platformio, arduino-esp32, mpu6050

I would like to use my MPU6050 together with my [ESP32](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/AZDelivery-NodeMCU-Development-Successor-Module/dp/B07Z83MF5W/ref=sr_1_5?crid=1199QZL2H91OW&keywords=esp32&qid=1657119596&sprefix=esp3%2Caps%2C170&sr=8-5). (Link to the specific ESP Board)

It is not the first time for me using the MPU6050. I used it before in a project with an Arduino Uno and the MPU6050_light.h library. That worked perfectly. Now i'm trying it with my new ESP32.

I tried the MPU6050_light and Adafruit MPU6050 libraries but the first returns

> MPU6050 status: 2

and the last throws the error:

> Failed to find MPU6050 chip

The wires are definitely correct:

- GND->GND
- V3V->VCC
- SDA->PIN 21 (SDA PIN)
- SCL->PIN 22 (SCL PIN)

I used an I2C scanner to check if the MPU is found and what adress it has.
And that worked too. It is the standart adress `0x68`.
I observed that when I pull out one wire and than connecting it again, the found adress changes to `0x69`.

So the MPU was found.
Has anyone any idea what could be the solution to my problem?

Code with MPU6050_light.h

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <MPU6050_light.h>
#include "Wire.h"

MPU6050 mpu(Wire);

long angle = 0;
unsigned long timer = 0;

void gyroSetUp()
{
  byte status = mpu.begin();
  Serial.print("MPU6050 status: ");
  Serial.println(status);
  while (status != 0)
  {
  } // stop everything if could not connect to MPU6050

  Serial.println("Calculating offsets, do not move MPU6050");
  delay(1000);
  mpu.calcOffsets(true, true); // gyro and accelero
  Serial.println("Done!\n");
}

void PrintAngles()
{
  Serial.print("X: ");
  Serial.print(mpu.getAngleX());
  Serial.print("\tY: ");
  Serial.print(mpu.getAngleY());
  Serial.print("\tZ: ");
  Serial.print(mpu.getAngleZ());
  Serial.print("\n");
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println("Starting");
  Wire.begin();

  gyroSetUp();
}

void loop()
{
  mpu.update();

  if ((millis() - timer) > 1000)
  {
    PrintAngles();
    timer = millis();
  }
}
```

Code with Adafruit MPU6050

```
/* Get tilt angles on X and Y, and rotation angle on Z
 * Angles are given in degrees
 *
 * License: MIT
 */

#include "Wire.h"
#include <Adafruit_MPU6050.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>

Adafruit_MPU6050 mpu;
sensors_event_t a, g, temp;
float gyroX, gyroY, gyroZ;
float gyroXerror = 0.07;
float gyroYerror = 0.03;
float gyroZerror = 0.01;
unsigned long lastTime = 0;
unsigned long gyroDelay = 10;

void initMPU()
{
  if (!mpu.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to find MPU6050 chip");
    while (1)
    {
      delay(10);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("MPU6050 Found!");
}

void getGyroReadings()
{
  mpu.getEvent(&a, &g, &temp);

  float gyroX_temp = g.gyro.x;
  if (abs(gyroX_temp) > gyroXerror)
  {
    gyroX += gyroX_temp / 50.00;
  }

  float gyroY_temp = g.gyro.y;
  if (abs(gyroY_temp) > gyroYerror)
  {
    gyroY += gyroY_temp / 70.00;
  }

  float gyroZ_temp = g.gyro.z;
  if (abs(gyroZ_temp) > gyroZerror)
  {
    gyroZ += gyroZ_temp / 90.00;
  }

  Serial.print("X: ");
  Serial.print(String(gyroX));
  Serial.print("\tY: ");
  Serial.print(String(gyroY));
  Serial.print("\tZ: ");
  Serial.print(String(gyroZ));
  Serial.print("\n");
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  initMPU();
}

void loop()
{
  if ((millis() - lastTime) > gyroDelay)
  {
    getGyroReadings();
    lastTime = millis();
  }
}
```

Comment: I should note that i now use PlatformIO. It worked on the ArduinoIDE half a year ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root of the problem.

solution:
Adafruit_MPU6050.h

```
#define MPU6050_DEVICE_ID 0x68 ///< The correct MPU6050_WHO_AM_I value
```

this "0x68" must be changed to 0x98

ONLY in this line

NOT here :

```
#define MPU6050_I2CADDR_DEFAULT \
0x68 ///< MPU6050 default i2c address w/ AD0 high
```

it must stay the same 0x68

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for my specific problem.
It took 4h of my lifetime.
If you use the MPU6050_light.h there is a wrong function in the example-sketch:

`mpu.calcOffsets();`

You have to change it to:

`mpu.calcOffsets(true, true);`

I don't understand why this function is designed in that way, but it is ok to use it without parameters.

I still don't know why the other library won't work, but I hope I've saved others time in the future.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense given your question. You said the MPU6050 wasn't being found - in which case you'd never make it to that line of code, which occurred after the call to `begin()`.

Comment: The message that the MPU6050 is not found is a message from the Adaruit-Library. My fix was for the MPU6050_light-Library.